# i want to be able to store and display data from an array and inside localstorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I have created a piece of code to store data from an input field into an empty array. After i store the data inside of the array , i want this data to be saved in the localstorage. Now i am not familir with the localStorage for saving the array. But my point is what i want is that every time i add a new value to the array, and after i refresh the browser , i dont want to loos my  data  which is displayed in the browser window as shown in the example below, and i also want the data to be displayed in the browser all the time.

```
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="name" ><br>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="push"><br>
    <p id="para"></p>

<script>
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    var para =document.getElementById("para");
    var list =[];


    btn.onclick=function(){
        var name =document.getElementById("name").value;
        /* list.push(name); */
        var i;

        localStorage.setItem("list",JSON.stringify(list.push(name)));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"));

        for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
            n=list[i];
        }
        para.innerHTML+=n+"<br>";


    }

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`push()` returns the new length of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Return_value). So your code is putting the array's length into localStorage and not your array. Stringify `list` itself:

```
list.push(name);
localStorage.setItem("list",JSON.stringify(list));
```

Also if you want it when the page loads you need to change the assignment for the initial `list`

```
var list;
//use localStorage["list"] or if not set use a new empty array
if(localStorage["list"]){
  list = JSON.parse(localStorage["list"]);
  //if you want to display list on page load
  //otherwise dont need below loop
  for(let i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    n += list[i];
  }
  para.innerHTML = n+"<br>";
} else { 
  list = [];
}
```

Comment: Patrick and how should i make it able to not loos the data after i refresh the webpage

Comment: @eliot You don't lose the data on page reload, it is still in the `localStorage` if you mean make it so it displays the content on reload just use the for loop on load (like i have in the example)

Answer (score 1):

The part of saving the data is done well, but about retrieving the data on load isn't exactly right...

You could store the data in a variable then run a function to loop in this data and display it:

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"));
```

Comment: I got that , the code is working , but what i want is actuall after i refresh the webpage i want the data still to be able to be aviable in the browser as for example ,i put some random names inside the input field and these to be visible in the browser every time i refresh the page